Модуль Тинькофф и opencart 2.3 баг
Тинькофф модуль оплаты на opencart 2.3 выбивает ошибку

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Apr 25 17:17:56 MSK 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). Not Found

И не добавляет заказ к заказам  Хотя оплата проходит все отлично
Обнаружил, что заказы то падают но почему то со статусом пропавший, хотя все настроено в админке по статусам верно

Добро пожаловать на сайт, Станислав, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
